# Set options to array field in Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How can I pass options such as `required: true` or `default` to an **Array field**?

See the documentation [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays), it only shows examples like this one:

```
ArrayOfString: [String]
```

But I want to be able to do something like this:

```
ArrayOfString: { type: [String], required: true, default: ['one', 'two', 'three'] }
```

Maybe thats valid, but there are no examples like that one in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am using it with Mongoose version 2.4.9 and it works with the following syntax

```
ArrayOfString: {type: Array, default: ['a','b','c','d']}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, mongoose doesn't introspect into arrays to figure out if they're sparse or whatever. That's probably something you'd have to do with a pre-save hook.

Edit: I may have misunderstood your question. Are you just purely looking for the presence of any array in the field?

Comment: the presence, and providing a default for it. I guess I have to stick to middlewares

Comment: I don't know, there might be a way to define it kind of as you were - type: Array or something. But I'm afraid I've never done that.